# How to get pose from rtabmap rgbd_odometry with Kinect

Tags: slam, navigation, visual-odometry, ros-kinetic, rtabmap-odometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am having trouble using `rgbd_odometry` from `rtabmap_ros` package.

I would like to subscribe to the published topic `odom` (`nav_msgs/Odometry`) so that I can compute the pose of my robot over time.

Using `laser_scan_matcher` and `hokuyo`, for example, I subscribe to a topic named pose_stamped (`geometry_msgs/PoseStamped`) with this same goal.

I don't care about mapping right now. I just want the pose over time, in order to plot the path my robot displaced.

I am typing the following commands:

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch`
```

and

```
rosrun rtabmap_ros rgbd_odometry rgb/image:=/camera/rgb/image_raw dep/image:=/camera/depth/image rgb/camera_info:=/camera/rgb/camera_info
```

I can echo the three remaped topics above, but i keep receiving this warning about the base_link.

```
[ WARN] [1521072121.902733559]: odometry: Could not get transform from base_link to camera_rgb_optical_frame (stamp=1521072121.798015) after 0.100000 seconds ("wait_for_transform_duration"=0.100000)! Error="canTransform: target_frame base_link does not exist.. canTransform returned after 0.100796 timeout was 0.1."
```

Topic `/odom` shows nothing.

Could anyone please give me a hint how to start solving it?

I use Ubuntu 16.04 and ROS Kinetic.

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285469/how-to-get-pose-from-rtabmap-rgbd_odometry-with-kinect/) by [EduardoCota](https://answers.ros.org/users/30275/eduardocota/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-03-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-14**:
Are you sure that `base_link` exists? Can you post your `tf` tree?

**Comment by [EduardoCota](https://answers.ros.org/users/30275/eduardocota/) on 2018-03-15**:
Thank you for answering! @matlabbe suggestion worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try:

```
$ rosrun rtabmap_ros rgbd_odometry rgb/image:=/camera/rgb/image_raw depth/image:=/camera/depth/image rgb/camera_info:=/camera/rgb/camera_info _frame_id:=camera_link
```

**However**, make sure the depth image topic is registered to RGB camera. Like in this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/HandHeldMapping):

```
$ roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch depth_registration:=true
$ rosrun rtabmap_ros rgbd_odometry rgb/image:=/camera/rgb/image_rect_color depth/image:=/camera/depth_registered/image_raw rgb/camera_info:=/camera/rgb/camera_info _frame_id:=camera_link
```

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2018-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [EduardoCota](https://answers.ros.org/users/30275/eduardocota/) on 2018-03-15**:
Thank you very much, @matlabbe! It worked and now I can subscribe to `/odom` and plot the position over time.
However, is there any way to improve visual odometry executed with Kinect? Results are poor by now.

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2018-03-16**:
The source version can give slightly better results. Keep in mind that scanning surfaces without strong visual features will make the odometry drift a lot more. See more scanning tips [here](https://goo.gl/amDg34).

**Comment by [EduardoCota](https://answers.ros.org/users/30275/eduardocota/) on 2018-03-16**:
Do you mean the source version from the rtabmap_ros package? I already built from source.
Thank you for the tips!

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2018-03-16**:
Yes this is what I meant. You can also try playing with GFTT parameters: `$ rosrun rtabmap_ros rgbd_odometry --params | grep GFTT/`. Like adding parameter: `_GFTT/QualityLevel:=0.001". Increasing GFTT/MinDistance can give more uniformly distributed features in images.

**Comment by [EduardoCota](https://answers.ros.org/users/30275/eduardocota/) on 2019-01-28**:
@matlabbe, Thank you again!!!
I get the odometry, but it stills stopping during some tests.
First, I thought was moving the robot too fast that the VO could not match the features. But it occurs even moving slowly.
Since I'm using a Intel NUC, would you say it stops because of my system capacity?

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2019-01-29**:
If there are no visual features in the field of view of the camera, even if you move very slowly, VO will fail.

**Comment by [EduardoCota](https://answers.ros.org/users/30275/eduardocota/) on 2019-02-14**:
Ok! Thank you very much, @matlabbe! Have you published any paper that explains how VO with Frame-2-Map works?

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2019-02-14**:
Search "RTAB-Map as an Open-Source Lidar and Visual SLAM Library for Large-Scale and Long-Term Online Operation", link to preprint is on the project page: http://introlab.github.io/rtabmap/